# Selenium - selecting a dropdown option

Tags: php, selenium

I'm trying to select a drop down option by value. However I can't seem to do it with click or type functions.

I'm using JsonWireProtocol and just making simple calls, however I seem to have been stuck on this for a while.

I've tried the following

```
$element = $this->get_element('payment-credit-method-cc0-expirationMonth');
$this->click_element($element);

$this->type('payment-credit-method-cc0-expirationMonth', array('U+E015','U+E000','U+E015','U+E000'));
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: English sentences are delimited by full stops, not commas. And what is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: My bad, been working long hours and a bad habit, updated info though

Comment: OK, and what went wrong with your approach?

Comment: Just doesnt select anything what so ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how you would do it in ruby.
Assuming you want to select **November** as the month.

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "payment-credit-method-cc0-expirationMonth'").find_element(:css,"option[value='11']").click
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using WaitForElementPresent()(on the item you want to select) before selecting a value. Selenium is trying to find that element even before it appears I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I was migrating from Selenium 1 to Selenium 2 using only the JsonWireProtocol.

Depending which PHP bindings you're using, I did the following with [Facebook's bindings](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver).

Making a couple of assumptions about your code.  payment-credit-method-cc0-expirationMonth is an id of your select, and the month you're selecting is November with its option value of 11

```
$this->session->element("xpath", "//select[@id='payment-credit-method-cc0-expirationMonth']/option[@value='11']")->click()
```

I believe you can select "November" (the option's visible label) by doing this as well.

```
$this->session->element("xpath", "//select[@id='payment-credit-method-cc0-expirationMonth']/option[text()='November']")->click()
```

The bindings I used for Se1 had a $this->select() method, and it took me a bit to realize all I'm doing is selecting an element and clicking on it  :/

Answer (score 0):

Using Facebook's JsonWireProtocol PHP Bindings:

```
$el=$s->element("css selector", 'select[id="my_id"] option[value="gbp"]');
$el->click();
```

where $s is your session. (from [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/25))