# Click an option in dropdown menu using PHP Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using PHP Selenium Webdriver wrapper by [Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver). Can anyone please give me an example of how to click or select an option from a select drop down menu?

I have tried this:

```
$test = $driver->findElement( WebDriverBy::id('drop1').WebDriverBy::cssSelector("option[value='11']"));
$test->‌​click();
```

but it errors out:

> **Message** : Object of class WebDriverBy could not be converted to string

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720956/selenium-selecting-a-dropdown-option) link can help you !

Comment: not 100% sure how that would work for the Facebook wrapper, do you have an example

Comment: I tried this:   $test = $driver->findElement(
    WebDriverBy::id('drop1').WebDriverBy::cssSelector("option[value='11']"));$test->click(); but it errors out: "Message: Object of class WebDriverBy could not be converted to string"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
$test = $driver->findElement("css selector", 'select[id="drop1"] option[value='11']');
$test->‌​click();
```

Answer (score 17):

It should be

```
$test = $driver->findElement( WebDriverBy::id('drop1') )
               ->findElement( WebDriverBy::cssSelector("option[value='11']") )
               ->click();
```

If you are working on "select" tag, use `WebDriverSelect` instead.

```
$select = new WebDriverSelect($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('drop1')));
$select->selectByValue('11');
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you want click or select item?
If select than follow: [Facebook framework helper](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/e238b94b97f7a0d0eb321ab02c6eca3938509b82/lib/WebDriverSelect.php)

Works like:

> $selectingContainer = $driver->findElement("locator");
>
> $selection =  new WebDriverSelect($selectingContainer);
>
> $selection->selectByVisibleText($text);

"locator" - it is locator for dropdown menu element.

Comment: If I have to select another select list so I have to create new instance for it?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, hope it helps someone :)

```
findElement( WebDriverBy::cssSelector(
                        'div#sku-grid.grid-view table.items thead tr.filters td 
                         select[name="Pro[exception_type]"] option[value="inRetail"]'
                         ));`
```