# To select dropdown menu on PHP/selenium doesn't work

Tags: php, selenium, automation

I'm tring to select [this dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ne6T.jpg) using PHP/selenium.

My code is below:

```
sleep(3);
$driver->findElement( WebDriverBy::xpath("//*[@id='main']/form/section[2]/mer-select[1]/div/label/div[2]/select") )
->findElement( WebDriverBy::cssSelector("option[value='2']") )->click();
```

and I tried all attempts suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490225/click-an-option-in-dropdown-menu-using-php-selenium-webdriver).
Non of them works.

I want your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this **css**:

```
select.input-node.medium.placeholder[name='category1']
```

or this xpath:

```
//select[contains(@class,'input-node medium placeholder') and @name='category1']
```

represent unique node in HTMLDOM which means 1/1 matching node then you can use the below code to select the desired option from the drop down.

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath/css` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Code:**

```
$select = new WebDriverSelect($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector("select.input-node.medium.placeholder[name='category1']")));
$select->selectByValue('3');
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and xpath/css you suggested matches 1/1 node.
but the code gives me syntax error.

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: strtolower(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given in /Users/A/Documents/scripts/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebElement.php:259
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/A/Documents/scripts/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebElement.php(259): strtolower(Array)
...